# C# DataRow.ToString() automatically formats the string when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, formatting

I have been programming for a while, but I have never seen this happen so I'm kind of baffled as to what's happening. What I'm doing is I'm executing a SP on a database and just to test it's output before I actually use it I'm putting the rows into pipe delimited strings. For some reason when I set a textbox to these results it formats the dates from SQL Server into DateTime variables and 1.99 decimals into 1.9900 decimals.

Also just a note: I don't want to access the column data by calling specific columns by column name. I want to make it so that I can change and add columns to the SP in the database and this would continue to work and bring back all columns from the SP.

Also the seconds on the last datetime aren't the same because the queries were run at different times so no need to worry about that.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here??

Here is the code that gets the data and creates the pipe delimited strings:

```
private string GetHourlySales()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    DataTable tblData = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        string sql = "EXEC [dbo].[ryan_GetSalesSummary] 0";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                tblData.Load(dr, LoadOption.Upsert);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in tblData.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tblData.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                output.Append("|");
            if (i == tblData.Columns.Count - 1)
                output.AppendLine(row[i].ToString());
            else
                output.Append(row[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    if (tblData.Rows.Count > 0)
        return output.ToString();
    else
        return null;
}
```

Here is the output that it creates:
[image: incorrect formatting]

Here is what I get straight from SQL Server:
[image: correct formatting]

Comment: What you see in MSSQL manager is just a representation of the data that is there in the same way that your datatable is a representation of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your datatable does not consist of the strings you see when you query your database, it's typed, which means you have actual datatypes of the columns you selected. So `DateTime`s will get formatted like `DateTime`s and `Decimal`s as `Decimal`s. What you see is the default behaviour.

Comment: Oh ok. So it actually preserves the data type from SQL Server and pretty much calls the ToString() method on that data type in C# which will format it to a default string. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It tries to come as close as possible to the MSSQL datatype. Sometimes there is no 1:1 equivalent, but for your example, there should be.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I was thinking it knew it was a DateTime since it formatted it as such, but I didn't know how or that it preserved the data type from SQL Server. I guess you learn something new every day. Thanks again!